# Admob: how many banners should I use

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have an iOS App with many screens, and I was wondering whether it was a good idea to put multiple banner screens for each VC. (ie one banner for the homescreen, one for the gamescreen, one for the settings, etc)

Or should I just use one banner for the whole app?

Clarification: I'm trying to optimize revenue, and I'm wondering whether adding banners would increase revenue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple banners in single app. just add new banners in your adMob account

Comment: will using multiple banners increase revenue?

Comment: The revenue your app generates is largely dependent on two factors: A) the geographic composition of your traffic; B) the session depth of your traffic. If you have 1M DAUs, but most of them are in places like Malaysia or the Philippines, then you will make a lot less per user, whereas if all of your traffic is principally US or Western Europe, it could be much more. If you have something like a utility app where users enter and see 1 or 2 ads in a session, you will be able to command very high prices (eCPM).